# tic tac toe game on Android through TCP server

Tags: android

I have an Android Studio clients that need to be updated to the other player moves so I'm trying to make a endless loop for the client so he will listen to the server all the time but when I debugged it I saw that when it tried to readUTF and there was no data it stipped the loop

**My code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView cell1;
    Handler h;
    String myShape, opponentShape, messageRecieved,move,viewSpot;
    TableLayout table;
    StringBuffer incoming = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    ImageView ttl;
    StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
    int r,c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cell1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cell1);
        ttl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ttl);
        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
        h = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        whoAmI();
        listener();
    }

    public void listener() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.1", 999);
                    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        messageRecieved = input.readUTF();
                    String[] parts = messageRecieved.split(",");
                    r = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                    c = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                    move = parts[0];
                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            TextView tv = (TextView) table.findViewWithTag(r + "," + c);
                            tv.setText(move);
                        }
                    });
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    listener();
                }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.
Thanks for adding the code to your question, its essential to find the issue.

Please describe the issue closer then "it didnt work" so we can have a look where the code fails. Can u provide any actual error messages or stacktraces?

Comment: i debuged it and when there was no data and it tried it readUTF it`s just stopped the loop...